# How to solve this logarithmic equation: $ \ x^{3\log^3 x-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)\log x} = 100 \sqrt[3]{10}\ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, quadratics, substitution

**How to solve this?**

I am new to logarithms.

$$ \  x^{3\log^3 x-\big(\frac{2}{3}\big)\log x} = 100 \sqrt[3]{10}\ $$
All the logs have base $10$.

Comment: try taking the logarithm of both sides, isolate $\log(x)$$ and then raise it to an exponent 10.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you are new to logarithms and yet you are given a question like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's
$$\  (3\log^3{x}-\frac{2}{3}\log{x})\log{x} = 2\frac{1}{3}\ $$
and $\log{x}=t$

We get $$9t^4-2t^2-7=0,$$
which gives $t=1$ or $t=-1$ and the answer is:
$$\left\{\frac{1}{10},10\right\}$$

Comment: Let me solve....

Comment: i have got two solutions

Comment: for this error i got a nice inequality from you Michael

Comment: I am sorry, i had mistakenly left x and cube.

Comment: @Ravi Prakash I fixed my post for you. See now.

Comment: oh sorry Michael, it is $$2\frac{1}{3}=2+\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Is log³x same as (logx)³

Comment: Yes it is..... :) i got it! I also got t=±1.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Dr. Sonhard Graubner 2⅓ is same as 2+⅓

Answer (score 2):

$3log(3)+ (2/3)log(x)= log(27+ x^{2/3}$  so $x^{3log(3)+ (2/3)log(x)}= x^{log(27+ x^{2/3})}$.  Further, $100\sqrt[3]{10}= 10^{2+ 1/3}= 10^{7/3}$. So the equation becomes $x^{log(27+ x^{2/3})}= 10^{7/3}$ and taking the logarithm of both sides $(27+ x^{2/3})log(x)= 7/3$

Comment: @user247327 Your solution is total wrong! $3\log^3x\neq27$.

Comment: ?? I didn't say it was.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\log(100\sqrt[3]{10})=\log(100)+\log(\sqrt[3]{10})$$
and your equation
$$(3\lg(x)^3-\frac{2}{3}\lg(x))\lg(x)=\lg(100)+\frac{1}{3}\lg(10)$$

Comment: Yes, its a nice explanation .....As the RHS upon simplification gives 2 + ⅓

Comment: What is $\text{lg}$?

Comment: logarithm to the base $10$